# Getting multiple submit using for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am using a for loop to check whether the user has attached the required documents or not. Based on the success I am submitting it to the server. I would like to make it simple. Even the validation passes it should submit the data only once instead of many times.
I have put the submit inside the loop for each success it will submit the data.
can anyone suggest me how I can make it simpler?

```
function validateFile () {
  if (vm.imageURIs.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < vm.imageURIs.length; i++) {
      var data = vm.imageURIs[i];
      if (data.img && data.img.length > Config.ENV.FILE_SIZE) {
        var fileName = data.name || vm.i18n.documentNumber + (i + 1);
        Toast.message($translate.instant('DOCUMENTMAXSIZE', { name: fileName }));
      } else if (data.document_required === true && data.img.length === 0) {
        Toast.message($translate.instant('DOCUMENTREQUIRED', {name: data.name}));
      } else {
        applyScheme();
      }
    }
  } else {
    applyScheme();
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks simple enough to me.

Comment: @holydragon instead of submitting once it submits based on the data length

Comment: @holydragon i would like to submit only once if it passes the condition

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
break;
```

after

> applyScheme();

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp